# How can I break this std::shared_ptr reference cycle?

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, reference-counting

Normally, I would break a cycle of `shared_ptr`s with `weak_ptr`.  But I can't see how to do that in this example:

```
struct A;
struct B;
struct C;
struct D;

struct Cache {
    std::shared_ptr<A> a;
    std::shared_ptr<B> b;
    std::shared_ptr<C> c;
    std::shared_ptr<D> d;
};

struct A {
};

struct B {
    // Same 'a' as in the Cache
    std::shared_ptr<A> a;
};

struct C {
    // Holds a backreference to the cache
    std::shared_ptr<Cache> cache;
};

struct D {
    // Same 'c' as in the cache
    std::shared_ptr<C> c;
};
```

There are never any cycles between the `A`, `B`, etc.  The only cycles are backreferences to the `Cache`.  The `Cache` needs to stay alive as long as anybody (except the `Cache` itself) has a `shared_ptr<C>`, so just using `weak_ptr<Cache>` won't work.  For example:

```
std::shared_ptr<Cache> make_cache() {
    auto cache = std::make_shared<Cache>();
    cache->a = std::make_shared<A>();
    cache->b = std::make_shared<B>();
    cache->b->a = cache->a;
    cache->c = std::make_shared<C>();
    cache->c->cache = cache;
    cache->d = std::make_shared<D>();
    cache->d->c = cache->c;
    return cache;
}

void use_cache() {
    auto a = make_cache()->a;
    // No need to keep the Cache around

    auto b = make_cache()->b;
    // b->a must be valid

    auto c = make_cache()->c;
    // c->cache must be valid

    auto d = make_cache()->d;
    // d->c (and therefore d->c->cache, etc.) must be valid
}
```

I understand that in general this would require a garbage collector, but I'm hoping in this specific case there's some trickery that can be done with `shared_ptr`'s [aliasing constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr) (8) or something.

Comment: Hidden cyclic references actually cannot be solved with the standard c++ `shared_ptr` / `weak_ptr` idioms. You'll have to change your design.

Comment: As `c` and `cache` will always reference each other, maybe you should create a new class `CacheWithData` that contains a `Cache` and a `C`, and let `C::cache` and `Cache::c` use its reference count (`std::shared_ptr<C>(cwd, &cwd->c)`)

Answer (score 0):

> > "The Cache needs to stay alive as long as anybody (except the Cache itself) has a `shared_ptr<C>`."

This argues that C controls the ultimate lifetime of the entire structure.
Therefore, shouldn't the cache be composed into C?

Comment: `C` must also stay alive as long as anybody has a `shared_ptr<Cache>`.  Neither one is special.

Comment: @TavianBarnes are you saying that as long as any shared pointer to any part of the structure is valid, the entire structure is valid?

Comment: Ideally, yes, that's what I'm saying.

Comment: @TavianBarnes the constraint that `auto c = make_cache()->c;` must return a valid c is the problem, because prior to the cache pointer being returned by the function, the cache is the only owner of c. This is at odds with the constraint that c must be deleted if the cache holds the only pointer to it.

Comment: Sorry, that constraint is not exactly what I meant.  I meant that `c` must be alive as long as anybody holds a pointer to `C` or `Cache`.  If nobody holds a pointer to `Cache` any more, then `Cache::c` shouldn't keep `C` alive.